# Access SQL join question

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using MS Access.  I'm sorry that the title is vague--i just don't exactly know how to describe what type of problem this is, I just know that I need to join two tables or queries to solve it.

I have a `OrgHistory` table that shows which organization each person (by ID) joined on a certain date (you can only be a member of one org at a time):

```
Person | Org | JoinDate
-----------------------
123    | abc | 3/2/2011
456    | abc | 4/23/1925
123    | def | 5/12/2011
```

I also have an `Activities` table:

```
Person | Activity | ActivityDate
--------------------------------
123    | eat      | 3/23/2011
123    | sleep    | 6/25/2011
456    | walk     | 7/20/1985
```

I want to find out, for each record in `Activities`, which organization the person was a member of on the date of the activity.  I'm thinking this might involve converting the `JoinDate` values into a set of ranges and matching `ActivityDate` to the appropriate interval, but I'm a little confused about how to design the query in this case--how do I create ranges and match an individual value to a range?

I don't think `partition()` will work because I'm not trying to hold multiple `JoinDate` values in a known quantity of buckets.

Comment: I agree your `OrgHistory` table is missing a `LeaveDate` attribute: you should add a new `LeaveDate` column to your base table, add a sequenced key to ensure periods cannot overlap for the same person (hint: you need a `CHECK` constraint), then scrub the data **once** (@Banjoe's query looks promising for this).

Comment: +1 @onedaywhen - for using a leave date instead of an active/innactive boolean. Many people don't consider having to go back historically to find membership.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't promise this is the most efficient way, but it works in Access with the test data you provided:

```
SELECT a.person, a.activity, 
       (
        SELECT TOP 1 org 
          FROM orghistory AS o 
         WHERE o.person = a.person 
               AND o.joindate <= a.activitydate 
         ORDER 
            BY o.joindate DESC
       ) AS Org
  FROM activities AS a;
```

Comment: thanks!  good idea about taking the top membership date that's <= the activity date, that makes a lot of sense.